# Javascript push array into another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there any difference between the following code(with/without spread operator)?

```
let result = [];
let arr1 = [1,2,3];

result.push(arr1)
result.push([...arr1])
```

Comment: Try changing `arr1` (eg: arr[0]++), and log the `result`, you'll see the first gets changed as it's a reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first, without spreading, any modifications to the array at the 0th position in `result` will result in a change to the original `arr1` as well, and vice versa.

If you spread the array while pushing, though, such changes will not occur; the two arrays (one in `arr1`, one in `result[0]`) will be completely independent.

```js
let result = [];
let arr1 = [1,2,3];

result.push(arr1)

arr1[1] = 999;
console.log(result);
```

```js
let result = [];
let arr1 = [1,2,3];

result.push([...arr1])

arr1[1] = 999;
console.log(result);
```